# XKB: modifier when hold, dead key when tapped?

Tags: xkb

I discovered that one can use Compose files to output a keycode when a modifier is pressed and released "alone", which is handy (I though before that one had to compose at least two keys together). Is there a way to do the same but with a dead key as output rather than a standard keycode (to chain it with another key)? I.e. is there a way to get a dead key as "output" in a Compose file, or is there any other way to emulate this behavior?